# Which is correct: 'leaving at...' or 'leaving by...', '..end of this week'?

Tags: word-usage

My understanding of correct usage is 'leaving by end of this week', and that is what I have been using all along.

However looking at an example of 'informal letter', at an [IELTS preparation site](http://www.ieltsbuddy.com/ielts-letter.html), I find the use of the 'leaving at...' expression. And this the the source of my confusion.

Comment: "At" means more or less exactly that time.  "By" means at that time or earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They mean different things.

"I will leave by the end of the week" means you will leave at sometime before the end of the week . . . maybe tomorrow (Wednesday), maybe Friday, but definitely by the end of the week.

"I will leave at the end of the week" is more precise and means you will not leave before the end of the week, but will leave at the end (on Saturday, for instance).

Comment: Or to put it another way, "by the end" declares an open interval finishing at the end of the week, during which you might leave at any time. "At" declares a point at which you *will* leave, not before.